# Firebase V9 Database. Batching operations?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I batch multiple operations? I found this resource for `Firestore` https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions does `database` have something similar.

I wanted to push a new message collection when chat is created.

```
export const newChat = () => {
  return push(ref(db, "chats"),{
       ...
    })
    .then((data) => {
        update(ref(db, `chats/${data.key}`), {
        chat_id: key,
      });
        //push(ref(db, `messages/${data.key}`), {
         //text: "hello"
      //});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing can be accomplished with:

```
const newRef = push(ref(db, "chats"));
set(newRef, {
  chat_id: newRef.key,
  ...restOfYourObject
});
```

The call to `push` does not cause any network traffic yet, as push IDs are a pure client-side operation.